# Exposed Romex inside sink cabinet

Tags: electrical

Is it legal by the NEC to have exposed Romex cable inside a kitchen sink cabinet?

[image]

Comment: That's the inside of a base cabinet?? I'd be just as concerned about the CSST gas pipe.

Comment: Is that a problem and why ? Works great 3 years now

Comment: It looks like the NM should be secured / stapled down better in any case.

Comment: I can staple it, it's not a problem

Comment: @batsplatsterson NM cable has to be secured every 4.5', and within 12" of a box. It doesn't look like that photo is 4.5' wide. Though for neatness, a staple or two could be installed.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the inspector, and whether or not they consider it exposed to physical damage.